# How to create a custom loss that does not directly use the output of the network with pytorch

Tags: pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, loss-function, loss

I would like to create a custom loss that does not directly use the output of my network. Indeed, I need to create a loss that returns the difference between the result of a function f(x) (where x is the output of my network) and max(f(x)). Unfortunately my code doesn't work and I don't know how to proceed... Here is my code:

```
def forward(self, x, y, hidden):
    c_0 = Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size))
    y = torch.reshape(y, (y.shape[0], 1, 1))
    tmp = torch.cat((x, y), 2)
    output, (hn, cn) = self.lstm(tmp, (hidden, c_0))
    out = self.fc(output)
    return out, hn

def _train(self):
    num_epochs = 10
    num_iteration = 10

    save_loss_global = []
    save_loss_epoch = []

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        print("NOUVELLE EPOCH")
        X_train, Y_train = donneesAleatoires()
        self.maxRes = 0
        self.hidden = Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers, 1, self.hidden_size))
        tabY = torch.Tensor()
        tabY = torch.cat((tabY, Y_train), 1)
        for iteration in range(num_iteration):
            x_i = X_train[0]
            x_i = torch.reshape(x_i, (x_i.shape[0], 1, x_i.shape[1]))
            y_i = Y_train[0]

            outputs, self.hidden = self(x_i, y_i, self.hidden)

            YiPlus1 = self.function(outputs.detach().numpy().reshape(1, -1))
            self.optimizer.zero_grad()
            Yadd = Variable(torch.Tensor(YiPlus1))
            tabY = torch.cat((tabY, Yadd), 1)

            loss = self.my_loss(tabY, iteration)

            if YiPlus1 > self.maxRes:
                self.maxRes = YiPlus1
            if y_i.detach().numpy() > self.maxRes:
                self.maxRes = y_i.detach().numpy()

            #loss = Variable(loss, requires_grad=True)
            loss.backward(retain_graph=True)

            X_train = outputs

            Y_train = YiPlus1
            Y_train = Variable(torch.Tensor(Y_train))

            self.optimizer.step()
            save_loss_global.append(loss.item())
            if iteration == num_iteration -1:
                save_loss_epoch.append(loss.item())
            print(X_train)


def my_loss(self, target, epoch):
    if isinstance(target, np.ndarray):
        target = Variable(torch.Tensor(target))
    tmp = self.maxRes
    loss = target[0][0] - tmp
    if epoch > 0:
        for i in range(1, epoch + 1):
            loss = loss + (target[0][i] - tmp)
    loss = -loss
    return loss / (epoch+1)
```

Comment: 1. Check your network graph if the nodes are connected as you expect. 2. Calculate loss of specific samples and see if it matches your expectations.

Answer (score 2):

To calculate gradients based on loss, toolchain needs computation graph. Said graph is builded implicitly on forward pass, but to do so, all computations must use toolchain's tensors (no `.numpy()`s!) with preserved gradients (no `.detach()`s!). Try to rewrite your code accordingly, don't wory about doing computations outside `forward`, it is normal.
You can check your tensors are computed right way, printing them, should look like

```
print( myTensor )

tensor([[-2.9016, -2.8739, ... ,-2.8929, -2.9033]], grad_fn=<AliasBackward0>)
```